# How to measure the maximum value of a segmented ROI in ITK-snap?

Tags: image-segmentation, itk

How to measure the maximum value of a segmented ROI in ITK-snap?

After segmentation, I can only get mean and SD from the Volumes and Statistics.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess that ITK-SNAP does not expose maximum value of base image in a segment. You might want to use [3D Slicer](https://www.slicer.org/), and its [segment statistics](https://slicer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/modules/segmentstatistics.html) module.

Comment: Thanks. Does 3D slicer have a similar segmentation function as in ITK-SNAP?

Comment: It does, via Segmentations and Segment Editor modules. It has many more functions, so it is somewhat harder to learn.